# Unsure why I am getting beforeEach/afterEach hooks async test errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am totally lost on why I get these errors when every other test file is set up exactly the same and runs/passes correctly as they should but for this specific file it fails. Any help is appreciated.

> 1. Test all homepage icons: CHROME
>    "before each" hook for "test home icon":
>    Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>    (C:\Users\bfreeman.WP\OneDrive - Asset Health,
>    Inc\Desktop\selenium-node-tests-1\test\testIcons.js)
>    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
>    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
> 2. Test all homepage icons: CHROME
>    "after each" hook for "test home icon":
>    Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>    (C:\Users\bfreeman.WP\OneDrive - Asset Health,
>    Inc\Desktop\selenium-node-tests-1\test\testIcons.js)
>    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
>    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Here is my beforeEach and afterEach code:

```
const loginToSite = require('../src/actions/loginToSite.js')
const chromeDriver = require('../src/drivers/chrome.js');
const assert = require('assert');
const { By } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {until}=require('selenium-webdriver');


describe('Test all homepage icons: CHROME', function() {
    this.timeout(50000);
    let driver;
    
  beforeEach(async function() {
      driver = await chromeDriver(process.env.GRID_URL);
      await loginToSite(url, driver); 
  }) 

  afterEach(async function() {
    await driver.quit();   
  })
```

chrome.js code:

```
let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const { Builder, Browser } = require('selenium-webdriver');

module.exports = async function (gridUrl) {
    const driver= await new Builder()
                .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
                //.usingServer(gridUrl)
                .setChromeOptions(
                    new chrome.Options()
                        .addArguments([
                            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                            '--no-sandbox'   ,
                            '--headless'   
                    ])
                )
                .build()
    return driver;
}
```

loginToSite.js code:

```
const { By } = require("selenium-webdriver")
const { until } = require("selenium-webdriver")
//const bypassCoachingModal = require("../src/actions/bypassCoachingModal.js");
//const bypassFirstTimeLoginModal = require("../src/actions/bypassFirstTimeLoginModal.js");
module.exports = async function (url, driver) {
    await driver.get(url);
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#overview_card1_start_course_btn > td > div')));
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#overview_card1_start_course_btn > td > div")).click(); 
    await driver.findElement(By.css("div#login_pw input")).click();
    await driver.findElement(By.css("div#login_un input")).sendKeys("example user");
    await driver.findElement(By.css("div#login_pw input")).click();
    await driver.findElement(By.css("div#login_pw input")).sendKeys("example pass");
    await driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();
}
```